# Can I create XAML properties like in the "x" namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know that I can make attached properties, for example

```
public enum HideOption
{
  node,
  tree
}

public static class Hide
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty OptionProperty 
                = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ( "Option", 
                                                        typeof(HideOption), 
                                                        typeof(Hide), 
                                                        new PropertyMetadata(HideOption.node) ) ;

  public static HideOption GetOption ( DependencyObject obj )
  {
    return (HideOption)obj.GetValue(OptionProperty);
  }

  public static void SetOption ( DependencyObject obj, HideOption value )
  {
    obj.SetValue(OptionProperty, value);
  }
}
```

and use it on XAML nodes, like

```
<Grid m:Hide.Option="tree">
</Grid>
```

The attributes in the "x" namespace have a shorter syntax, like

```
<Grid x:Uid="MyGrid">
</Grid>
```

Is it possible to create my own attributes which would use this syntax, for example

```
<Grid m:Hide="tree">
</Grid>
```

or is it some special feature of the XAML Language not available to normal libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are not attached properties. The [x namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/namespace-language-features) contains XAML compiler directives. They are instructions to the XAML parser and compiler or code generator. Like [x:Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xclass-directive) tells the compiler to link the generated XAML class with a `partial` declared C# class (code-behind). This directives are no `DependencyProperties` and don't participate in the dependency property system like attached properties do.
Since this directives are compiler level, I don't think that you can create them. You would need a way to tell the compiler how to interpret this directives.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I had suspected.